# Rails show presence:true fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to display in console `presence: true` fields

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :description, presence: true
end
```

Like `Product.column_names` - show all fields

Looking for smth `Product.mandatory_columns` `=> ['title','description']`

Comment: Use `Model.validators` though it does not give the desired output as you need, you may need to iterate and prepare output as per your need but it gives all into about validations and attributes on given `Model`.

Answer (score 2):

This might vary a bit in different versions of Ruby on Rails, but I was able to get them using this method in Rails 4:

```
Model.validators.select{|v| v.kind_of?(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator)}.flat_map(&:attributes).uniq
```

or even shorter, as pointed out in the comment:

```
Model.validators.select{|v| v.kind == :presence}.flat_map(&:attributes).uniq
```

Comment: shorter: v.kind == :presence

Answer (score 0):

Why not put it in the constant?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  MandatoryColumns = %i[title description]
  validates_presence_of *MandatoryColumns
end
```

rails console:

```
Product::MandatoryColumns => [:title,:description]
```

<sub>[KISS is an acronym for "**Keep it simple, stupid**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)</sub>

Comment: what is `%i[...]`?

Comment: An array of symbols.

Comment: haha. your solution is better IMO, but it was a mistake to reference KISS principle on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create your own method with the following [methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validators) :

- validators
- validators_on

With these methods, you'll be able to list all validations about your class with your criterias.